# Bootstrap "errors" - are these any important?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a bootstrap project and I've stumbled across some [bootstrap errors](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki)

- Containers (`.container` and `.container-fluid`) are not nestable
- Only columns (`.col-*-*`) may be children of `.row`s
- Some others, but they do not matter

Here is some simplified HTML, that would give the same errors:

```
<div class="contaner-fluid">
  <div class="contaner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table">
        </div>
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I'm not looking for a way to fix them**, I know how to do it myself.

The questions that bothers me is:
**Do these errors matter?** Fixing them would take more time (re-thinking the layout) than just ignoring them, since these do not look like they affect the actual page in any way.

Or am I missing something ?

Comment: they are bootstrap rules, not css rules. As long as css is valid i guess it doesn't matter. I wouldn't call it errors, more like warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are just trying to get you to follow good practice with bootstrap, I used to write code like this when I first started using bootstrap and a few times it caused me massive headaches because I could end up with margins in the wrong places or text and content skewed to the left or right. Or it would look good on desktop and then when I shrink it down to mobile it would look terrible.

Or worse I would come back to some code after a few months and find it takes me 10x longer to add in some functionality because making space for it causes the design to collapse in on itself. I found to fix this I either had to go back and write it correctly or write lots of 'hacky' CSS overrides.

I try and follow the rules the best I can from the beginning, now maintenance and updates are far easier to complete. Also it allows other developers to understand and edit my code better.

There may even be some benefit to your SEO value as google checks for valid HTML code, although the code above is not technically HTML invalid there could be some cases where it is.